# Is Luke 21:24 an allusion to Daniel 7:25?

Tags: luke, daniel, nt-use-of-hebrew-bible, intertextuality, great-revolt

Both passages speak of the "trampling" of Jerusalem and both by gentiles and both for a specified, limited time period referred to as "times":

> [Luk 21:24 NIV] (24) They will fall by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations. **Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles** **until the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled.**
>
> [Dan 7:19-28 CSB] (19) "Then I wanted to be clear about the fourth beast, the one different from all the others, extremely terrifying, with iron teeth and bronze claws, devouring, crushing, **and trampling with its feet whatever was left**. (20) "I also wanted to know about the ten horns on its head and about the other horn that came up, before which three fell ​-- ​the horn that had eyes, and a mouth that spoke arrogantly, and that looked bigger than the others. (21) **"As I was watching, this horn waged war against the holy ones and was prevailing over them (22) "until the Ancient of Days arrived and a judgment was given in favor of the holy ones of the Most High**, for the time had come, and the holy ones took possession of the kingdom.  (23) "This is what he said: 'The fourth beast will be a fourth kingdom on the earth, different from all the other kingdoms. It will devour the whole earth, **trample it down**, and crush it. (24) "The ten horns are ten kings who will rise from this kingdom. Another king, different from the previous ones, will rise after them and subdue three kings. (25) "He will speak words against the Most High and oppress the holy ones of the Most High. He will intend to change religious festivals and laws, and **the holy ones will be handed over to him for a time, times, and half a time**. (26) "But the court will convene, and his dominion will be taken away, to be completely destroyed forever. (27) "The kingdom, dominion, and greatness of the kingdoms under all of heaven will be given to the people, the holy ones of the Most High. His kingdom will be an everlasting kingdom, and all rulers will serve and obey him.'  (28) "This is the end of the account. As for me, Daniel, my thoughts terrified me greatly, and my face turned pale, but I kept the matter to myself."

The Daniel "times" reference seems to refer to the last 3.5 years of the Great Revolt of circa 70ad. This is the "great tribulation". [History tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War#Aftermath) that despite all, the Jews sprang back after the war:

*...Despite the upheaval brought by the revolt, the Jewish people remained resilient. The demolishing of the Temple, Jerusalem, and the farming lifestyle of the economy and land of Israel did not stop the Jews from succeeding and excelling in Judea. They worked hard within the system created by the Romans and thrived...*

Schiffman, Lawerence (1991). "Revolt and Restoration," in From Text to Tradition. Ktav Pub. House. pp. 161–162.

So is it possible that Daniel and Luke both refer to the same army "trampling" on the Jews for "times" specified in Daniel? It is easy to see the possibility of a connection but I'm fuzzy on the details.

Please see the [Preterist Commentary here](https://revelationrevolution.org/#shortcuttoPRETERISTBIBLECOMMENTARYONALLMAJORENDTIMEBIBLEVERSES) and search for "Daniel 7".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Luke 21:24, "the trodding down of Jerusalem" is from the prophesy of Daniel 7:25.  It does not "allude" to it, as an "allusion" is a passing or casual reference that implies indirect similarity.  The prophesy in Luke 21 is the same prophesy of Daniel 7.

But, the site you have referenced, though it has much that is correct, also is greatly confused because they have not stayed within the context of the scriptures, and so have wandered off the path in certain areas.

The focus is the trodding down of Jerusalem, not of Rome.  The count of the kingdoms are the count of the succeeding world powers which began with Babylon.  Dan. 7:3 defines these world powers as *"four great beasts that came up from the sea"*.  As the sea in prophesy symbolized the nations beyond the "land" or "earth" of Israel / Judah / Jerusalem, they were the pagan nations of the world beyond Jerusalem.

As first pagan nation revealed in Dan. 2:36-49, the first was Babylon described as a lion with eagles wings (Dan. 7:4).  The second which devoured the first kingdom was Medo-Persian empire ruled by Cyrus and Darius and described as a bear with three ribs in its mouth - the act of devouring.  The third in sequence was the Greco-Macedonian empire succeeded under Philip and his son Alexander, and described as a leopard with four heads - Alexander's four generals (Dan. 7:6).

The fourth world power that arose was the ancient world power of the Roman empire and it's description is key.

> *"After this I saw in the night visions, and behold a fourth beast, dreadful and terrible, and strong exceedingly; and it had great iron teeth: it devoured and brake in pieces, and stamped the residue with the feet of it: and it was diverse from all the beasts that were before it; and it had ten horns."*  (Dan. 7:7, KJV)

Note that the fourth world power that devoured the other three kingdoms, stamping the "residue" with its feet was different from the other three that had preceded it, and IT HAD TEN HORNS.  Horns of the beasts were symbols of kings that ruled each kingdom. The ten kings were of the fourth beast.  They belonged to and were out of the fourth world power, and therefore were 10 kings / rulers of Rome.  They cannot have been kings or rulers of any other nation, and so were not any Zealot rulers of Jerusalem as Jerusalem was not a world power, nor a pagan nation.

The description from Dan 2:33 having feet of iron and clay is the imagery of intermixed nations as Rome had absorbed aspects of the Greco-Macedonian empire, which had absorbed elements of the Medo-Persian empire before it; which had in turn absorbed elements of the Babylonian empire before it.  The different elements were not cleaving to each other, and the ancient Roman empire was not able to hold them all together.

The context of the scriptures is paramount. Dan. 7:19-25 gives us several details which define the time frame for the full establishment of Christ's heavenly kingdom.

> *"19 Then I would know the truth of the fourth beast, which was diverse from all the others, exceeding dreadful, whose teeth were of iron, and his nails of brass; which devoured, brake in pieces, and stamped the residue with his feet;*
>
> *20 And of the ten horns that were in his head, and of the other which came up, and before whom three fell; even of that horn that had eyes, and a mouth that spake very great things, whose look was more stout than his fellows.*
>
> *21 I beheld, and the same horn made war with the saints, and prevailed against them;"*

The fourth world power was different from the preceeding three in several respects. The ten horns were Roman rulers.  Rome began as a representative republic with senatorial provinces and regional governors that reported to the Senate, transforming over time into a Greco-Roman principate with elected consuls.  But, the Roman general Gaius Julius Caesar was of the aristocracy and one of the few remaining patrician families of Rome.  Through his military conquests Julius began consolidating power and with an economic and political consortium / triumvirate with Pompey and Crassus, came to be a military dictator which over-ruled the Senate in 46/45 BC, and was the ultimate cause of his assassination in 44 BC.(1)

It was under Gaius julius Caesar that Rome became the 4th world power foretold by Daniel 2 and 7. So, the first ruler or king, the first horn of that empire was Julius Caesar.  The other nine kings were also of the Roman empire, and we count from Julius on to the sixth ruler which was Nero.  At Nero's death, the year of four emperors occurred AD 68/69 in which three rulers who were not of the Julian line tried to take the reigns - Galba, Otho, & Vitellius.

Whereas Galba used the title of Caesar, Otho at first used the title of "Nero" before eventually adding Caesar.

> *"And the ten horns out of this kingdom are ten kings that shall arise: and another shall rise after them; and he shall be diverse from the first, and he shall subdue three kings."*  (Dan.7:24, KJV)

The confusion comes from the rendering of "after them" that makes it seem as though there were eleven kings of this kingdom.  However, we have to go back to Dan.7:8 to realize that the king that subdues three others is from "among" the ten.

> *"I considered the horns, and, behold, there came up among them another little horn, before whom there were three of the first horns plucked up by the roots: ..."* (KJV)

So, there were ten kings in all, not eleven.  Beginning with Julius Caesar that makes Vespasian the tenth. The tenth was the little horn that grew in power and was different than the others before him.  The difference was that Vespasian was a Flavian, not of the Julian line, and did not attempt to recall the Julian line by mimicking Nero as both Galba, and Otho had done.

The tenth king / ruler put down three before him.  Galba, Otho and Vitellius all attempted to grasp the reigns of Rome during the "time, times, and half a time" (Dan. 7:25) when Vespasian was sent to put down the rebellion in Judea.  It was during that second year of the Roman-Jewish wars that Vespasian had to break off and lead his troops back to Rome to take control of the empire.  He left his son Titus in charge of the war in Judea.

Titus did not put down or abase his father.  Titus inherited the throne from his father Vespasian.  So, Titus cannot have been the little horn that put down three others before him.  That was Vespasian.

The "end" of the prophesies of Daniel was not the end of the Roman empire, nor the end of the line of the Caesars. The end would occur during that fourth kingdom, and was the end of the desolations of Jerusalem (Dan. 12:6-7).  The destruction of the temple in Jerusalem was the focus.  It was the end of the Mosaic covenant; the end of the animal sacrificial system in that temple.  And, that was time when all power was given to Christ as the fullness of the heavenly kingdom was brought into all power over all of the kingdoms of the earth.

The end of the prophesies was the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem in AD 70, and that was the fulfillment of the trodding down of Jerusalem by the gentiles. (2) (3)

> *"But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they tread under foot forty and two months."*  (Rev. 11:2, KJV)

Notes:

1) Julius Caesar - [here](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Julius-Caesar-Roman-ruler/Antecedents-and-outcome-of-the-civil-war-of-49-45-bce)

2) Frequent Mistakes - Part I: Rev. 13:3 The Wounded Head [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/11/18/frequent-mistakes-part-i-rev-133-the-wounded-head/)

3) Frequent Mistakes - Part II: The Ascension of Christ [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/11/19/frequent-mistakes-part-ii-the-ascension-of-christ/)

Answer (score 0):

**General Theme!** The Answer given by Gina most nearly fits the intentional message of the prophecy of Daniel 7! The four Beasts do represent ancient empires: (1)BABYLON noting that much of its architecture has symbols of lions (See Jer. 4:7). (2) MEDO-PERSIAN which conquered Babylon in 539 B.C. The flesh that Persia devoured was Media, actually a land overrun and occupied by Asian barbarians. (3)GREECE which is appropriately symbolized by a swift Leopard (panther) with four wings. Alexander the Great is known for the vast amount of territory conquered in such a short time. The "four heads" represent the Diodochi, four generals who took over the empire after Alexander died.

And (4)ROMAN empire which dominated the "Iron Age." Iron teeth and bronze claws represent the co-mingling of Italy and Greece economically, socially, and militarily. During Roman supremacy, the Greek culture proliferated, hence the N.T. written in Greek to supplement the Greek LXX.

This wild, diverse Beast was identified as Roman in the Apocalypse of Baruch (2-1 century B.C.)  And also in the Fourth Book of Ezra (Esdras) (1 century A.D.

> *I also wanted to know about the 10 horns on its head and about the other horn that came up, before which three of them fell--that horn that looked more imposing than the others...* (Daniel 7:20)

> *The ten horns are ten kings who will come from this kingdom. After them another king will rise, different from the earlier ones; he will subdue three kings. He will speak against the Most High and oppress His saints and try to change the set times and the laws. The saints will be handed over to him for a time, times, and half a time.* (7:24-25)

**King Row** While the list of kings of Rome may start from Julius Caesar and end with Vespasian, as some advocate. A search of Roman history ends up with a *better fit*. Notice that when the prophecy said "kings" it did not demand that they be "Caesars" or emperors, or Czars, or dictator, or even Presidents. The Roman rulers picked up titles along the way, e.g. Augustus, or a name of a patron. So the list of these Roman kings does not have to begin with a known "Caesar."

History records the first "dictator" of Rome to be Lucius Cornelius Sulla. (81-79 B.C.) So if we begin our counting with him, the prophecy fits history perfectly.

1. Sulla---
   Triumvirate (Pompey, Crassus, Caesar
2. Julius Caesar---
   Triumvirate (Antony, Octavian, Lepidus
3. Octavian, Augustus
4. Tiberius
5. Caligula
6. Claudius
7. Nero

---

8. Galba
9. Otho
10. Vitellius

---

11. Vespasian (invader of Judea)

**Vespasian the Oppressor** It was this general-turned emperor that was responsible for the TRAMPLING of the whole land of Judea. He was the short, stout king (7:8) who was "different". That is, Vespasian was not of the Julio-Claudio royal line, but was a plebe of the Flavian family. After the humiliation of general Cestius, who had gone to Judea to aid the procurator, Gessius Florus, in his conflict with the Roman-hating Zealots, Nero sent Vespasian to quell the revolt.  He arrived at Ptolemais with 3 Legions.

> *The saints were handed over to him for a time, times, and a half a time.* (7:25 three and a half years)

Vespasian, in the Spring of 67 A.D., began his methodical repression if the Jewish revolt. One by one Jewish fortresses fell throughout Galilee. Then he turned to the coastal cities, and this was accomplished by the end of the year.

In the campaign of 68, Vespasian systematically subdued Judea, and the fortresses of Perea. Then from the north he marched down the western part of Judea, as far south as Idumea, to cut off any support from them. Then back up north looping through Samaria.

In the third year, 69 A.D. he had succeeded in taking all the surrounding country and the Jews were left with only Jerusalem, Herodium, and Masada.  They were isolated from all foreign aid and supplies.

In 70 A.D. Titus was put in charge, while Vespasian went to Rome to become emperor. Titus marched on Jerusalem with four Legions (the V, X, XII, XV). By the Fall of 70 A.D. Jerusalem had fallen after the most horrible destruction---mostly caused by the Zealot in-fighting. (See Daniel 12:1, Matthew 24:21) The final stroke was delayed by a Zealot hold-out in one of Herod's strong fortresses by 45 days.  Thus the time listed in chapter 12 was brought into play (1290--->1335) [See Flavius Josephus, Wars of the Jews] Chapter 12 is the only other place where *time, times and half a time* is mentioned (v. 7), linking chapter 7 with the time in chapter 12.

**Trampled Down** This time of conquest is exactly what was recorded in Luke 21:24.  *Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles (nations) until the Times of the Gentiles (nations) are fulfilled.* The very wording of Luke's verse speaks of a set time---not an indefinite span of years, as some speculate. Notice that it doesn't simply say that Judea will be an occupied territory (e.g. by the Ottomans, Egyptians, Crusaders, Germans, etc.).  But that it will *be trampled on*, crushed by the iron boots of the dreaded fourth beast.

The use of the Greek word, *ethnic*, translated "Gentiles" or "nations" is most appropriate and accurate.  The composition of the Roman fighting Legions and auxillary units was Roman AND foreign mercenary soldiers. Different Legions were composed of different national soldiers that had been conquered by Rome.

**Conclusion** Yes, Luke 21:24 is a fulfillment of what was prophesied in Daniel 7:25...to the letter! {Liberal theologians cannot gainsay the supernaturalness of this prophecy since the events of the Fall of Judea occurred way past the 2nd century B.C., which they allege was the time of a pseudo-Daniel's writing.}

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that Jesus prophesy in Luke 21:20-24 has a time frame way beyond Daniel's prophesy in Daniel 7:19-28. Therefore the question if Luke 21:24 an allusion to Daniel 7:25 is plausible.

> They will fall by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations. **Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles until the times of the Gentiles are fulfilled**. (Luke 21:24 NIV)

Immediate follow Luke 21:24, Jesus talked about his 2nd coming. Would vv21:24 refer only to the destruction of Jerusalem in 70AD, or it refers to a subsequent time frames?

The statement indicate Jerusalem is trampled by the Gentiles but there is an end of it. Therefore the answer is do we see the end yet. And if the end means Jerusalem no longer trampled by the Gentiles, what should it be liked, a city of the Jews or a city of God?

Though the Romans Empire fell, the Holy Romans Empire fell, and Israel rebuilt their nation in 1948, Jerusalem is currently a place of both Jews and Gentiles. Therefore I don't see Jesus' prophesy in Luke 21:24 alludes to Daniel's prophesy, nor it had fulfilled. the times of the Gentiles is more likely explained by Paul in his epistle of Ephesians

> 11 Therefore, remember that formerly you who are Gentiles by birth and called “uncircumcised” by those who call themselves “the circumcision” (which is done in the body by human hands)—
>
> 12 remember that at that time you were separate from Christ, excluded from citizenship in Israel and foreigners to the covenants of the promise, without hope and without God in the world.
>
> 13 But now in Christ Jesus you who once were far away have been brought near by the blood of Christ.
>
> 14 For he himself is our peace, who has **made the two groups one** and has destroyed the barrier, the dividing wall of hostility (Ephesians 2:11-14 NIV)

It refers a time that the Gentiles entitled in the new covenant, that the Jews and the Gentiles were made one by the blood of Christ.